# Cómo generar un objeto desde un formulario - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Dispongo de dos clases:

- Disco
- Tienda

Los discos se guardan en la tienda siempre y cuando al introducirlos en un formulario estén correctamente rellenados los campos. **Si todo está OK**, pulsamos el botón "**Guardar disco**" y llamaremos a la función **addDisco(disco)**, función a la cual le pasamos el disco con los datos del formulario.

Mi duda está en los comentarios siguientes: ¿cómo relleno con los datos del formulario un objeto de tipo Disco? ¿Se puede crear un div para mostrar el error en caso de que: "El campo nombre no es correcto"?

**Os dejo el código probado y testeado de las clases Disco y Tienda.**

```
//Clase Disco. Le pasamos los atributos necesarios. Método constructor.
var Disco = function(nombre, cantante, ano, tipo, estanteria){
    this.nombre = nombre; 
    this.cantante = cantante;
    this.ano = ano;
    this.prestado = false;

    //Comprobamos que existe el tipo de musica pasado por argumento.
    comprueba_tipo = function(tipo){
        //Array de tipos de musica.
        var array_tipos = ["rock", "pop", "puck", "indie"];
        //Si no existe en el array... establecemos la primera posición de éste.
        if(array_tipos.indexOf(tipo)<0){
            return array_tipos[0];
        }else{
            return tipo;
        }
    }

    //Establece la propiedad tipo de musica en funcion parametro tipo.
    this.setTipoMusica = function(tipo){
        this.tipo = comprueba_tipo(tipo);
    }
    this.tipo = comprueba_tipo(tipo);


    //Comprobamos que la porpiedad estanteria sea un valor entre 1 y 10. En caso
    //contrario, establecer el valor 0 por defecto.
    var comprueba_estanteria = function(estanteria){
        //Si la estanteria está entre 1 y 10, OK!
        if(isNaN(new Number(estanteria))){
                estanteria = 0;
        }else{
            //Si no esta entre 1 y 10, por defecto toma el valor 0.
            if(estanteria<1 || estanteria>10){
                estanteria = 0;
            }
        }
        return estanteria;
    }

    //Establece la propiedad estanteria validando que sea un valor numerico entre 1 y 10.
    this.setEstanteria = function(estanteria){
        this.estanteria = comprueba_estanteria(estanteria);
    }
    this.estanteria = comprueba_estanteria(estanteria);

    //Cambia la propiedad del estado del disco.
    this.presta = function(nuevoEstado){
        this.prestado = nuevoEstado;
    }

    //Metodo toString().
    this.toString = function(){
        return "El nombre del disco es "+this.nombre+" del cantante "+this.cantante+" fue publicado en "+this.ano+" de tipo de musica "+this.tipo+" en la estanteria "+this.estanteria+". Prestado: "+this.prestado+"";
    }
}


//Comprobar la clase. Creamos un objeto pasandole datos a los argumentos.
/*var miDisco = new Disco("MachupichuPop", "Osmar", 1990, "pop", 8);
console.log(miDisco.toString());
miDisco.presta(true);
miDisco.setEstanteria(3);
miDisco.setTipoMusica("mamamam");
console.log(miDisco.toString());*/


//Clase Tienda. Constructor sin parametros.
var Tienda = function(){
    //Creamos un array de discos.
    this.numTotalDiscos = new Array();

    //Devuelve el numero total de discos.
    this.getNumeroDiscos = function(){
        return this.numTotalDiscos.length;
    }

    //Devuelve el numero de discos que no estan prestados.
    this.getNumeroDiscosDisponibles = function(){
        var cantidad = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<this.numTotalDiscos.length; i++){
            if(this.numTotalDiscos[i].prestado==false){
                cantidad++;
            }
        }
        return cantidad;
    }

    //Añade un disco al array.
    this.addDisco = function(disco){
        this.numTotalDiscos.push(disco);
    }

    //Muestra los titulos de los discos almacenados.
    this.getTituloDisco = function(i){
        return this.numTotalDiscos[i].titulo;
    }

    //Devuelve el objeto Disco que esta en la posicion i-esima.
    this.getDisco = function(pos){
        return this.numTotalDiscos[pos];
    }

    //Elimina el disco cuyo titulo coincide con el que se pasa como parametro.
    this.deleteDisco = function (titulo){
        for(var i=0; i<this.numTotalDiscos.length; i++){
            if(this.numTotalDiscos[i].nombre == titulo){
                this.numTotalDiscos.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Devuelve verdadero si existe el disco cuyo titulo coincide con el que se pasa.
    this.existeDisco = function(tituloRecibido){
        var existe = false;
        for(var i=0; i<numTotalDiscos.length;i++){
            var titulo = this.numTotalDiscos[i].nombre;
            if(titulo==tituloRecibido)
                existe = true;
                break;
        }
        return existe;
    }

    //Modifica el titulo de un disco si existe.
    this.modificaDisco = function(titulo, nuevoDisco){
        for(var i=0; i<this.numTotalDiscos.length; i++){
            if(this.numTotalDiscos[i].nombre == titulo){
                this.numTotalDiscos[i] = nuevoDisco;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
}


//Creamos una tienda, y en ella insertamos varios discos para comprobar el funcionamiento.
var miTienda = new Tienda();
var miDisco1 = new Disco("MachupichuPop111", "Osmar111", 1989, "pop", 3);
miDisco1.presta(true);
var miDisco2 = new Disco("MachupichuPop222", "Osmar222", 1990, "pop", 8);
var miDisco3 = new Disco("MachupichuPop333", "Osmar33", 1956, "indie", 11);
miDisco3.presta(false);
miTienda.addDisco(miDisco1);
miTienda.addDisco(miDisco2);
miTienda.addDisco(miDisco3);
console.log(miDisco1);
console.log(miDisco2);
console.log(miDisco3);
console.log("Tengo "+miTienda.getNumeroDiscos()+ " disco/s en la tienda");
console.log("Tengo "+miTienda.getNumeroDiscosDisponibles()+ " disco/s prestados en mi tienda");
console.log("En la posicion 3 está el objeto Disco:[[[ "+miTienda.getDisco(2)+" ]]]"); //[2] es la posicion 3, empieza a contar el array desde pos[0].
```

**Código HTML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Mi tienda de discos</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/formulario.css" />
        <script src="js/disco.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/tienda.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/formulario.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Tienda de discos</h1>
        <form id="formulario"> 
            <div id="informacion" class="linea_formulario">
            </div>
            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre del disco</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"  />
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="cantante">Cantante</label>
                <input type="text" name="cantante" id="cantante"  />
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>          

            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="anio">Año</label>
                <input type="text" name="anio" id="anio"  />
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>          
            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="estanteria">Estantería</label>
                <input type="text" name="estanteria" id="estanteria"  />
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>          

            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="favorito">Tipo de música</label>
                <select name="tipo" id="tipo">
                    <option selected value="none">Elige uno...</option>         
                    <option  value="rock">Rock</option>
                    <option value="pop">Pop</option>
                    <option value="punk">Punk</option>
                    <option value="indie">Indie</option>
                </select>                       
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="prestado">Prestado:</label>
                <div class="botones">
                  <input type="radio" name="prestado" id="prestado_si" value="si" /><span>Si</span>
                  <input type="radio" name="prestado" id="prestado_no" value="no" checked="checked"/><span>No</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="linea_formulario">  
                <input type="button" id="guardar" value="Guardar disco" /> 
                <input type="button" id="eliminar" value="Eliminar disco" />
                <input type="button" id="ver" value="Ver disco" />
                <input type="button" id="modificar" id="enviar" value="Modificar disco" />                      
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>

            <div id="listado" class="linea_formulario">
                Todavía no tienes ningún disco.
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Código Javascript (aquí las dudas, mirar comentarios):**

```
/*Creo un objeto/instancia de la clase Tienda.*/
var miTienda = new Tienda();

/* Registro un evento para cuando termine de cargarse el documento se cargen los eventos necesarios.
 */
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, true);

//Función que se ejecuta tras cargarse el documento y registra el resto de eventos.
function iniciar(){
    //Evento para validar que los campos estén con información correcta y NO estén vacíos.
    document.getElementById('guardar').addEventListener('click', validarCampos, false);
}


/******************************************************************************
 **************** FUNCIONES PARA LA COMPROBACION DE LOS CAMPOS ****************
 ******************************************************************************/

//Función que se encarga de validar los campos del formulario.
function validarCampos(evento){
    //Valido los diferentes apartados del formulario. Si todo está OK...
    if (validarCamposText(this) && comprobarNombre() && comprobarCantante() && comprobarAnio() && comprobarEstanteria() && confirm("¿Desea enviar el disco?")){
        return true;
        //Guardamos el disco en la tienda. Para ello tenemos la variable/objeto tienda llamada "miTienda".
        //Si todo está correcto, llamaremos a la función "GuardarDisco()". A la cuál tendremos que pasarle el objeto Disco, ¿no?
    }else{
        //Cancelar el evento por defecto del envío del formulario.
        evento.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}


//----------------------------------------------------------//
//Funcion para validar todos los campos input de tip "text".
function validarCamposText(objeto){
    //La propiedad form del botón enviar contiene la referencia del formulario dónde está ese botón submit.
    var formulario = objeto.form;

    //Recorremos en un array todos los elementos del formulario.
    for (var i=0; i<formulario.elements.length; i++){
        //Eliminamos la clase Error que estaría asignada a algún campo.
        formulario.elements[i].className="";
    }

    //Recorremos en un array todos los elementos del formulario.
    for (var i=0; i<formulario.elements.length; i++){
        //Escogemos los que son de tipo "text" y los que están vacíos...
        if (formulario.elements[i].type == "text" && formulario.elements[i].value.trim()==""){
            //Mostramos en un div, llamado "errores", un mensaje para el usuario de que el campo está vacío.
            document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="El campo "+formulario.elements[i].name+" no puede estar vacío.";
            formulario.elements[i].className="error";
            formulario.elements[i].focus();
            return false;
        //Aprovechamos para tratar el campo "Año", sólo debería admitir un valor numérico entre 200 y 2017.
        }else if (formulario.elements[i].id=="anio"){
            if (isNaN(formulario.elements[i].value) || formulario.elements[i].value <2000 || formulario.elements[i].value >2017){
                document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="El campo "+formulario.elements[i].name+" es incorrecto o el año no está entre 2000 y 2017.";
                formulario.elements[i].className="error";
                formulario.elements[i].focus();
                return false;
            }
        }else if (formulario.elements[i].id=="estanteria"){
            if (isNaN(formulario.elements[i].value) || formulario.elements[i].value <0 || formulario.elements[i].value >10){
                document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="El campo "+formulario.elements[i].name+" es incorrecto o la estantería no está entre 0 o 10.";
                formulario.elements[i].className="error";
                formulario.elements[i].focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


//Función para comprobar que el campo nombre no está vacío.
function comprobarNombre(){
    if (!document.getElementById("nombre").value.trim()==""){
        var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
        //console.log(nombre);
        return true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="El campo NOMBRE es obligatorio.";
        document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
        return false;
    }
}

//Función para comprobar que el campo cantante no está vacío.
function comprobarCantante(){
    if (!document.getElementById("cantante").value.trim()==""){
        var cantante = document.getElementById('cantante').value.trim();
        //console.log(cantante);
        return true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="El campo CANTANTE es obligatorio.";
        document.getElementById("cantante").focus();
        return false;
    }
}

//Función para comprobar que el campo anio no está vacío. Se deberá controlar con una expresión
//regular que tenga el formato: 2003, 2013, 2015... --> 4 dígitos.
function comprobarAnio(){
    //4dígitos.
    var patron = /^\d{4}$/;
    //Analizamos el patrón.
    if (patron.test(document.getElementById("anio").value)){
        document.getElementById("anio").className="";   
        return true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="El campo AÑO es obligatorio.";
        document.getElementById("anio").focus();
        return false;
    }
}

//Función para comprobar que el campo estanteria no está vacío.
function comprobarEstanteria(){
    if (!document.getElementById("estanteria").value==""){
        var estanteria = document.getElementById('estanteria').value;
        //console.log(estanteria);
    }else{
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="El campo ESTANTERIA es obligatorio.";
        document.getElementById("estanteria").focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: utiliza los constructores que declaraste para crear los objetos disco y meterlos como parametro en el método GuardarDisco

Comment: que base de datos estas usando?... las clases que creaste están bien para el manejo del discos / Tienda dentro del cliente (FrontEnd) pero esta información debes guardarla en un servidor, que (BackEnd) estas usando del lado servidor? PHP, Python, Perl?

Comment: No es nada de servidores. Todo está hecho con Javascript. Almaceno los discos en una tienda, pero todo en el lado cliente. Cada vez que recargo la página los datos se van al olvido.

Comment: @fwBasic No uso lado servidor, todo desde el cliente, cuando recargo la página se borran todos los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nombre = document.getElementById("inputNombre").value;    
var cantante = document.getElementById("inputCantante").value;
var ano = document.getElementById("inputAno").value;
var tipo = document.getElementById("inputTipo").value;
var estanteria = document.getElementById("inputEstanteria").value;
var disco = new Disco(nombre,cantante,ano,tipo,estanteria);
```

En el caso de un radio button sería así:

```
var radioButtons= document.getElementsByName('nombreRadio');
var radio;

for (var i = 0, i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
    //Así cogemos el valor del radio que esté checked
    if (radioButtons[i].checked) {
        radio = radioButtons[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Así tendrías el objeto disco con los datos de los input y solo quedaría añadirlo con addDisco.

Comment: Sigo teniendo dudas de cómo coger el valor de cada campo y agregarlo al objeto Disco, perdona. Un pequeño ejemplo me ayudaría. ¿Cada método me debe retornar el valor de cada campo? ¿O los puedo recoger todos de golpe?

Comment: El valor de un input en javascript se coge así: `document.getElementById("idDelInput").value`, esto te retornaría el valor del input

Comment: ¿y en los elementos de tipo select o radio? ¿Igual?

Comment: en el radio sería un pelín diferente, edito la respuesta

Comment: miTienda.addDisco(disco);

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59226/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-g3l0).